# Change username - more people with same username

Tags: discussion

Recently made me a user of gis.stackexchange.com. I can see there is an older user, with the same username as mine. Tried to change my username, but there is a 1 month delay. Are there any reason why usernames are not required to be unique? I know this is only an issue up front, since stackexchange uses another key to separate user with the same name regarding profiles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some arguments are:

1. In real life there are repeated names,
2. If your are not the first one to come up with a name, you would need to try a lot (depending on the situation) to get a unique ID.
3. Everyone should be able to use his own name.

There are other arguments.

Below, there are 2 other Stack Exchange threads that discuss this issue, and they also have advice if one wants to avoid repeated IDs.

For example: add a nickname after the real name.

[Why does Stack Overflow allow duplicate display names?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25404/why-does-stack-overflow-allow-duplicate-display-names)

[Identical username for two distinct active accounts allowed by the system?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1836/identical-username-for-two-distinct-active-accounts-allowed-by-the-system)